# docker build tini tcsetpgrp failed: Permission denied

Tags: docker

My **entrypoint.sh**

```
exec /sbin/tini -s -- /usr/bin/spark-operator "$@"
```

but when i run docker, it logs:

```
[FATAL tini (6)] tcsetpgrp failed: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue could occur for many reasons and the lack of privileges isn't always what might be wrong. 
In many cases the file you are coping isn't a runnable file. Try to make it runnable by adding the following to your Dockerfile after you have copied your file.

```
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/spark-operator
```

The other option might be that you lack the right privilege to execute the file.

Try adding the file as a user, if you are creating one, or run the file as root which is not good code of conduct. To add a file to your Docker container with a specific owner enter the following in your Dockerfile.

```
ADD --chown user:group spark-operator /usr/bin/spark-operator
```

Read more about this at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add
or

```
COPY --chown user:group spark-operator /usr/bin/spark-operator
```

Read more about this at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy